How to fix error: linker command failed with exit code 1 in React native - Xcode
ld: 13 duplicate symbols
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Any one help me how to resolve this issue,
I am facing this issue when I build my project using xcode15.
My project is working perfectly in android,In IOS I received this error.I tried this steps add "-ld64" to under LInking-general steps.
